# Auto or Random Scatterplot Matrix Selections d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, simulate

I would like to know if there is a way to have some sort of random selection, or any selection happening when this loads and to stop when a user interacts with it. AS it stands now, people do not realize that they can interact with the chart.

Maybe the top left box could have a selection being drawn and receding?

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/iris-splom.html

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: How about just adding a note telling people that and how they can interact with the charts?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw the brush programatically using the [extent()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-brush_extent) method.

also, look at some of the examples in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/vNaR-vJ9hMg).

Using the same example you posted, add this to the end of the csv callback:

```
var e = [[0.4,1.4],[1.4,2.4]]; //set brush range
brush.extent(e);    
cell.call(brush);              //draw brush
```

and if you want the brush to simulate user interaction:

```
cell.select(".extent")
.transition()
.attr('width',20).attr('height',20)
.attr('x',10).attr('y',10)
.transition()
.attr('width',80).attr('height',80);
```